# Mathematica edit list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I wanted to delete pair with the same argument and leave the pair with the lowest value, for example we have list:

```
data={{0.1, 1},{0.2, 15},{0.1, 7},{0.1, 11},{0.3, 27}};
```

And I want to get:

```
data={{0.1, 1},{0.2, 15},{0.3, 27}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.1, 7}, {0.1, 11}, {0.3, 27}};

First /@ GatherBy[SortBy[data, First], First]
```

> {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.3, 27}}

Answer (score 6):

```
f = DeleteDuplicatesBy @ First @* Sort;

f @ data
```

> ```
> {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.3, 27}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.1, 7}, {0.1, 11}, {0.3, 27}};

MinimalBy[#, First, 1] & /* First /@ GatherBy[data, First]

(* {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.3, 27}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.1, 7}, {0.1, 11}, {0.3, 27}};
```

Using `Merge` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
Merge[Min] @ MapApply[Rule] @ data
```

<|0.1 -> 1, 0.2 -> 15, 0.3 -> 27|>

```
KeyValueMap[List][%]
```

{{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.3, 27}}

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.1, 7}, {0.1, 11}, {0.3, 27}};
```

---

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
Values@GroupBy[data, First, First]

(*{{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 15}, {0.3, 27}}*)
```